# Show current date in WPF Toolkit Date Time picker

Tags: wpf, toolkit, datetimepicker

I am using codeplex wpf toolkit and want to show current date at the bottom of calendar same as date time picker of windows form shows, tried various properties but could not find a solution. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly,you want to show the current selected date in the calender part of the datepicker.For that you want to customize the control template of the Datepciker COntrol.Go through the link below to get started

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx

**Edit**

To have a Today Button in the calender check the below thread

http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/85516?ProjectName=wpf

Comment: This will show current date selected, i want to show current date on the bottom side of datetimepicker window

Comment: No its not the one i am looking for i am using datetimepicker of wpf toolkit from codeplex and at the bottom of calender i want to show today date and when user clicks it, it current dates get selected. For example user naviagted to some future date and he wants to set current date then there is no option he has to select current year then current month and then current date where as in dattimepicker of windows current date was displayed in bottom and user can select it any time

Comment: @user751975  Oh you are looking to have a "today" button.See my Edited answer

Comment: i accept the answer done some changes in the code suggested on link and then I was able to achieve what i wanted